# Pro-finite completion of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then if $\Omega(X)$ denotes the set of equivalence relations $\sim$ on $X$ such that $X/\sim$ is a finite set, the pro-finite completion of $X$ is defined to be the limit
$$\hat{X}:=\text{lim}_{\sim\in \Omega(X)} X/_\sim.$$

By the work of Hoechster, we know that profinite $T_0$-topological spaces are spectral. I'm having a some trouble seeing which properties of $X$ transfer to $\hat{X}$. For instance, if $X$ is $T_0$, does it follow that $\hat{X}$ is $T_0$? If $X$ is a loop space, i.e. there exists some $Y$ such that $X\cong \Omega Y$, does it follow that $\hat{X}$ is a loop space, i.e. that there exists a $Z$ such that $\hat{X}\cong \Omega Z$? Can we tell when a topological space is the completion of a CW-complex?

Comment: What do you mean by a loop space?

Comment: By the way, under the definition I am used to, the profinite completion is the inverse limit of all finite discrete quotients (which makes it automatically compact Hausdorff), not all finite quotients.

Comment: @tomasz I took the definition from https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1540417825, and that is also the definition I'm used to, so this confuses me (that we two have different ones). As for what I mean by a loop space: I mean that there exists some $Y$ such that $X=\Omega Y$. I'll clarifiy this in the question!

Comment: The profinite completion can be described more concretely as the set of ultrafilters on $X$, topologized by saying if $U$ is open in $X$, then the set of ultrafilters containing $U$ is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The profinite completion of a topological space is typically a horribly pathological sort of space.  Let me first describe it more concretely.  The points of $\hat{X}$ are naturally in bijection with ultrafilters on $X$: given ${\sim}\in\Omega(X)$ and an ultrafilter $F$, exactly one equivalence class of $\sim$ will be in $F$.  It is not hard to show that the choices of equivalence classes which are compatible and thus give an element of $\hat{X}$ are exactly those which come from an ultrafilter in this way.  The natural inclusion $X\to\hat{X}$ is then just the inclusion of the principal ultrafilters.  The topology on $\hat{X}$ also has a simple description when you identify $\hat{X}$ as the set of ultrafilters on $X$: it is the topology generated by sets of the form $S_U=\{F\in\hat{X}:U\in F\}$ where $U\subseteq X$ is open.  Note that restricted to principal ultrafilters, this is just the given topology on $X$, so the natural inclusion $X\to\hat{X}$ is an embedding.

Now, let $B$ be the Boolean algebra generated by the open subsets of $X$.  For pretty much any space of interest, $B$ is going to be a proper subalgebra of the full power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$.  (For instance, if $X=\mathbb{R}$, it is easy to see that $B$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ whereas $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.)  This means that there are distinct ultrafilters on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ which have the same intersection with $B$.  That is, there are distinct ultrafilters on $X$ which contain the same open sets.  That means there are points of $\hat{X}$ which are in exactly the same open sets in its topology, so $\hat{X}$ is not $T_0$.

So, $\hat{X}$ will usually not be $T_0$, even for very nice spaces.  Here is another example of how $\hat{X}$ can be bad: suppose $x\in X$ is any non-isolated point.  Then there is some nonprincipal ultrafilter $F\in\hat{X}$ which converges to $x$.  This means that every closed set which is in $F$ contains $x$, or in other words that every closed subset of $\hat{X}$ which contains $F$ also contains the principal ultrafilter $F_x$ at $x$.  In particular, this shows $\hat{X}$ is never $T_1$ if $X$ is not discrete.

However, when $X$ is compact Hausdorff, at least the homotopy type of $\hat{X}$ is well-behaved: $\hat{X}$ deformation-retracts to $X$.  If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then every ultrafilter on $\hat{X}$ has a unique limit in $X$; let $L:\hat{X}\to X$ be the map which takes each ultrafilter to its limit.  Define $$H:\hat{X}\times[0,1]\to\hat{X}$$ by $H(F,t)=F$ for all $t<1$ and $H(F,1)=L(F)$ (here we identify $X$ as a subset of $\hat{X}$ in the natural way, so that $L(F)\in\hat{X}$).  I claim $H$ is continuous, and so is a deformation retraction from $\hat{X}$ to $X$.  It is clear $H$ is continuous on $\hat{X}\times[0,1)$.  For continuity at $t=1$, suppose $F\in\hat{X}$ and $U\subseteq X$ is open such that $H(F,1)\in S_U$; we must find a neighborhood $V$ of $(F,1)$ such that $H(G,t)\in S_U$ for all $(G,t)\in V$.  Note first that $H(F,1)=L(F)\in S_U$ just means that $L(F)\in U$ (thinking of $L(F)$ as a point of $X$ rather than a principal ultrafilter).  Since $X$ is regular, there is an open neighborhood $W$ of $L(F)$ whose closure contained in $U$.  Since $F$ converges to $L(F)$, we have $W\in F$.  Moreover, for any $G\in\hat{X}$ such that $W\in G$, we have $L(G)\in\overline{W}\subseteq U$.  It follows $H(G,t)\in S_U$ for any $(G,t)\in S_W\times[0,1]$, so we can take $V=S_W\times[0,1]$ as the desired open set.